# Vue instance `watcher` not called during SSR with Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a plugin with the following code:

```
   let vm = new Vue({
      data: {
        foo: 1,
      },
      watch: {
        $data: {
          deep: true,
          handler(){
            console.log('changed')
          }
        }
      }
    })

    vm.foo = 123; // should trigger watcher
```

The problem is that the message `'changed'` is printed only clientside, meaning that the watcher is not called serverside during SSR? Any explanation to this behavior? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by serverside? do you want to send your data to the server?

Comment: The code is in a Nuxt plugin, so it is executed both during SSR and on the client, but behaves differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small implementation with pure Vue SSR: https://codesandbox.io/s/oqx461ll8z

The result is a bit different than expected. The watcher will drigger after the SSR process with the latest value. As there is no reactivity on the server and Vue has to prefetch data for consistency and perf reasons ([source](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/universal.html#data-reactivity-on-the-server)), this what will happen.

Result:

```
<div data-server-rendered="true">123</div>
{ foo: [Getter/Setter] } 123 123
changed
```

Comment: Oh, now I see that reactivity is by default disabled on the server. Thanks!